# How should multiple versions of .net be installed on the same machine?

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, rider

The linked "duplicate" question has nothing about side-by-side installs of multiple versions. It only covers command line installs.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. with .net SDK 7.0.202 and JetBrains Rider.

.Net 7 was installed following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#register-the-microsoft-package-repository) by adding the Microsoft package respository as an apt source.

I can build and run .net 7 projects.

I can build .net 6 projects but if I try and run it I get:

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /home/duncan/Projects/github/AvaloniaEdit/src/AvaloniaEdit.Demo/bin/Debug/net6.0/AvaloniaEdit.Demo
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet

The following frameworks were found:
  7.0.4 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

What is the correct way to install multiple versions of .net side by side?

Comment: How did you install .NET 7?

Comment: @Charlieface I have updated the question with info. I installed it using apt after adding the MS package repo.

Comment: Have you tried `apt install dotnet-runtime-6.0`

Comment: No errors but doesn't seem install anything. `dotnet --version` and `dotnet --list-runtimes` only list the existing 7.0 and cannot run 6.0 apps.

Comment: Is there no output at all from that command?

Comment: It prints typical apt spam mostly about dependencies. It includes "Setting up dotnet-runtime-6.0 (6.0.113-0ubuntu1~22.04.1) ..." but as I say, it hasn't changed anything that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

(Installing *newer* versions of the SDK and framework is easy: run the install instructions from https://dotnet.microsoft.com or use your package manager.)

On windows, I've been able to install multiple *older* SDKs just by downloading the relevant double-clickable installers, so my first attempt on linux would be to still try following the download instruction for 6.0 at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

**But** if that doesn't get you the right result, then the next step is the command line script installation instructions at

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install

in which you use a shell to download MS's bash installer script, and then tell it which runtime or SDK you want. e.g.

> ./dotnet-install.sh --version 6.0

Or, possibly (given the exact error message you got) you might try

> ./dotnet-install.sh --version 6.0.0

but I don't think you should need a match in the 3rd part of the version number, I think you only need the first 2 parts of the version to be a match, and any `6.0.x` version should do.

You should then be able to verify that you have a Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.x runtime installed with:

> `dotnet --info`

under the 'Runtimes' section of the output. e.g. I get:

```bash
>dotnet --info

.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.101
 Commit:    bb24aafa11

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  13.2
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.101/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.1
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       97203d38ba

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.424 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.202 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.402 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  6.0.404 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  7.0.101 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.30 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.12 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.30 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.15 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.3 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.12 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

The side-by-side installs should 'just work' – when you run an older dotnet project, if the relevant Runtime version is installed, then the dotnet cli uses it.

Comment: Instead of version, use the channel flag. To install the most recent version of 6.0: 

`./dotnet-install.sh --channel 6.0`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with Ubuntu 22.04 when my dotnet packages were installed from different package repositories - dotnet 6 and dotnet 7 from archive.ubuntu.com, and dotnet 8 from packages.microsoft.com.  Only the dotnet 8 runtime was recognized, preventing me from running dotnet 6 programs (a similar error to OP above)

Directions on the fix are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup?pivots=os-linux-ubuntu#solutions, in the "I need a version of .NET that isn't provided by my Linux distribution" section.

Basically,

1. apt remove all dotnet installs
2. create an apt preferences file to avoid archive.ubuntu.com as a package source
3. apt install all dotnet installs, so they all come from packages.microsoft.com as a package source.